# How to fix linear model fitting error in S-plus

Tags: r, s-plus

I am trying to fit values in my algorithm so that I could predict a next month's number. I am getting a No data for variable errror when clearly I've defined what the objects are that I am putting into the equation.

I've tried to place them in vectors so that it could use one vector as a training data set to predict the new values. Current script has worked for me for a different dataset but for some reason isn't working here.

The data is small so I was wondering if that has anything to do with it. The data is:

```
 Month  io   obs    Units Sold
 12     in    1    114
 1      in    2    29
 2      in    3    105
 3      in    4        30
 4      in    5
```

I'm trying to predict Units Sold with the code below

```
 matt<-TEST1

 isdf<-matt[matt$month<=3,]
 isdf<-na.omit(isdf)
 osdf<-matt[matt$Units.Sold==4,]

 lmfit<-lm(Units.Sold~obs+Month,data=isdf,na.action=na.omit)

 predict(lmFit,osdf[1,1])
```

I am expecting to be able to place lmfit in predict and get an output.